# Set background colour of HVScrollView item on click

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have implemented the HVScrollView custom renderer in Xamarin.Forms as below and am trying to set the background colour of the item selected on tapped/clicked but can't figure out how to do that.

I can't figure out whether I need to add something to the custom renderer to make it show the selected item or whether it should be set in my markup.

Please help

```
public class HVScrollGridView : Grid
{
    private ICommand _innerSelectedCommand;
    private readonly ScrollView _scrollView;
    private readonly StackLayout _itemsStackLayout;

    public event EventHandler SelectedItemChanged;

    public StackOrientation ListOrientation { get; set; }

    public double Spacing { get; set; }

    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("SelectedCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(HVScrollGridView), null);

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(HVScrollGridView), default(IEnumerable<object>), BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: ItemsSourceChanged);

    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(HVScrollGridView), null, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnSelectedItemChanged);

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(HVScrollGridView), default(DataTemplate));

    public ICommand SelectedCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(SelectedCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void ItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var itemsLayout = (HVScrollGridView)bindable;
        itemsLayout.SetItems();
    }

    public HVScrollGridView()
    {
        _scrollView = new ScrollView();

        _itemsStackLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            BackgroundColor = BackgroundColor,
            Padding = Padding,
            Spacing = Spacing,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        _scrollView.BackgroundColor = BackgroundColor;
        _scrollView.Content = _itemsStackLayout;
        Children.Add(_scrollView);
    }

    protected virtual void SetItems()
    {
        _itemsStackLayout.Children.Clear();
        _itemsStackLayout.Spacing = Spacing;

        _innerSelectedCommand = new Command<View>(view =>
        {
            SelectedItem = view.BindingContext;
            SelectedItem = null; // Allowing item second time selection
        });

        _itemsStackLayout.Orientation = ListOrientation;
        _scrollView.Orientation = ListOrientation == StackOrientation.Horizontal
            ? ScrollOrientation.Horizontal
            : ScrollOrientation.Vertical;

        if (ItemsSource == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var item in ItemsSource)
        {
            _itemsStackLayout.Children.Add(GetItemView(item));
        }

        _itemsStackLayout.BackgroundColor = BackgroundColor;
        SelectedItem = null;
    }

    protected virtual View GetItemView(object item)
    {
        var content = ItemTemplate.CreateContent();
        var view = content as View;

        if (view == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        view.BindingContext = item;

        var gesture = new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = _innerSelectedCommand,
            CommandParameter = view
        };

        AddGesture(view, gesture);

        return view;
    }

    private void AddGesture(View view, TapGestureRecognizer gesture)
    {
        view.GestureRecognizers.Add(gesture);

        var layout = view as Layout<View>;

        if (layout == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var child in layout.Children)
        {
            AddGesture(child, gesture);
        }
    }

    private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var itemsView = (HVScrollGridView)bindable;

        if (newValue == oldValue && newValue != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        itemsView.SelectedItemChanged?.Invoke(itemsView, EventArgs.Empty);

        if (itemsView.SelectedCommand?.CanExecute(newValue) ?? false)
        {
            itemsView.SelectedCommand?.Execute(newValue);
        }
    }

    public static explicit operator ListView(HVScrollGridView v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add codes about how to use `HVScrollGridView`? For example, how to set the `ItemsSource`? Where to place `HVScrollGridView`?

Comment: itemsView.SelectedItem.BackgroundColor = Color.Gray; --> Can you check if BacgroundColor property is exist in SelectedItem. Or you must cast into your child type and access the color property over it